# JTextField text display

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, settext

I am trying to get some text displayed inside `JTextField`, the text should be taken from an `ArrayList` to which i add text using the `addText` method. I also want to be able to cycle through the Strings in the `ArrayList` using buttons.

`Text` class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Text {
    private String text;

    public Text (String text)
    {
        this.text=text;
    }

    public String getText()
    {
        return text;
    }
}
```

`TextDisplay` class

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class TextDisplay
{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField text;
    private JButton next;
    private JButton back;
    private ArrayList<Text> someText;
    public TextDisplay ()
    {
        makeFrame();
        someText= new ArrayList<Text>();
    }
    public void addText(String text)
    {
        Text sText = new Text(text);
        someText.add(sText);
    }
    private void makeFrame()
       {frame = new JFrame("text");    
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();


        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));

        text = new JTextField();
        text.setEditable(false);
        contentPane.add(text, BorderLayout.NORTH);   

        back = new JButton("back");
        panel.add(back);
        next = new JButton("next");
        panel.add(next);

        contentPane.add(panel,BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.pack();

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Can someone explain or show an example to me of how to achieve this?

Comment: Let TextDisplay class implements ActionListener, and set this class as ActionListener of back and next buttons.

Comment: Make an **ActionListener** in the **Next** and **Back** Button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to add an `ActionListener` to your button, then add the logic of getting the value from the `ArrayList`.

**For Example:**

```
int index = -1;
next.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            index++;
            text.setText(someText.get(index).getText());
        }
    });
```

Then you could add a variable index to get the next element in the `ArrayList` and then update that variable when you get the element.

Comment: Thank you.. but how do i make it display text in the first place?

Comment: Where did you get the setText from? is it a method i need to write?

Comment: No, its build in method inside the `JTextField` class, it the method that responsible to set the text that should be display in the `JTextField`. i suggest you read any basic book for Swing :)

Comment: Because i get an error that methos setText in javax.swing.text cannot be applied to given types.. Reason:actual argument text cannot be converted to java.lang string

Comment: Yea because get return a `Text` object, the you need to get the text from that `Text` object, so just call `getText()`, that will save your life, see my updates.

Comment: Another small question.. it gives me an error when i write the same code for back button.. i set index-- but it doesnt go back.. i just get this (at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
)